# How to save a string plus its state into List?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, list, idictionary

I have this following Code in C# using EF Core 1.2 where I'm reading the input of a textarea and check each line if it matches one of my patterns.
After checking one line I'm trying to set a state which tells me if it matches one pattern.

Now I would like to save these lines temporary plus each of its state into a list so I can pass this list to my view, where I want to display each line plus its state in a table.

My problem is how do I save each line plus its state? I thought about using a Dictionary but I'm not sure if this is the best solution for my problem.

```
using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(Request.Form["ExpressionTextarea"].ToString()))
{
    string line = string.Empty;

    do
    {
        line = reader.ReadLine();

        if (line != null)
        {
            string state = CheckStringLine(line);

            /**** HOW TO SAVE EACH LINE PLUS ITS STATE TEMPORARILY?
            //IDictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            //dictionary.Add(line, status);
            ****/
        }
    } while (line != null);

    //***PASSING MY LIST TO MY VIEW
    return View(MYLIST);
}

//Checks if line matches a pattern
public string CheckStringLine(string Line)
{          
    string state = "";
    //Pattern1: (Ein | Eine) A ist (ein | eine) B.
    string pattern1 = @"^(?<Artikel1>(Ein|Eine){1})\s{1}(?<Second>[A-Z]{1}[a-zäöüß]{1,})\s{1}ist\s{1}(?<Artikel2>(eine|ein){1})\s(?<Fourth>[A-Z]{1}[a-zäöüß]{1,})\.$";

    //Pattern2: (Ein | Eine) A (oder (ein | eine) B)+ ist (ein | eine) C.
    string pattern2 = @"^(?<First>(Ein|Eine){1})\s{1}(?<Second>[A-Z]{1}[a-zäöüß]{1,})(\s{1}oder\s{1}(?<OptionalArtikel>(ein|eine){1})\s{1}(?<OptionalBegriff>[A-Z]{1}[a-zäöüß]{1,}))+(\s{1})ist\s{1}(?<Third>(eine|ein){1})\s(?<Fourth>[A-Z]{1}[a-zäöüß]{1,})\.$";

    var match1 = Regex.Match(Line, pattern1);
    var match2 = Regex.Match(Line, pattern2);

    if (match1.Success)
    {
        state = "This Line is using pattern1";

        return state;
    }
    if (match2.Success)
    {
        state = "This Line is using pattern2";
        return state;
    }           

    state = "No matches";
    return state; 
}
```

Comment: A dictionary sounds good as long as every key is unique. Otherwise have a look at C# 7´s tuple datatype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `Dictionary` is for situations where you want a key/value pair and I understand here you just want to store things. Also if you want to keep the order it wouldn't work.

The easiest way is to use a `List` containing a `Tuple`, if you don't want to create your own type for this.

```
var list = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
list.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(line, state));
```

Then when you need them you can get the tuples from the list and get the line from `Item1` and the state from `Item2`.

Comment: Or even an anonymous type var v = new { Amount = 108, Message = "Hello" };  is possible

Comment: @TomSchardt Can you put an anonymous type into a List type safely?

Comment: new[]{ new{Value="string1",State="state1"}, new{Value="string2",State="state2"}}.ToList();

Answer (score 0):

You can user any in-memory data structure to store your state. HashTable will be much faster than other data structures but it is not generic. You can use Dictionary as well, which is generic.